# Why Office 2007 override Windows regional date setting?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, regional-settings

I have a problem with a specific user's computer running windows XP SP2 and Office 2007. Although she has the regional date setting in windows to dd/mm/yyyy, her office applications are still reverting to mm/dd/yyyy which is driving her (and me) nuts.

None of our other machines is doing this. Does anyone have a clue as to what to be looking for as the source of this irritating problem?

Comment: Does this go for all Office programs or just one in particular?

Comment: Can you post more details on the regional settings on this computer compared to the ones that work.

Comment: Is Outlook connected to Exchange?

Answer (score 0):

From the friends of [Experts Exchange:](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Email_Servers/Exchange/Q_23362234.html)

> I changed the separation symbol from
>   "/" to "-" and oddly enough it worked
>   after that!

Note: you have to change this in XP's regional settings.

So dd-mm-yyyy